# can we alias(save to a variable) a class method in php

Tags: php, class, function, methods, alias

here is an example class:

```
public class example
 {
     private $foof;         

     public function __construct()
     {
          $this->foof = $this->foo;
     }

     public function foo($val=0)
     {
             // do something...
     }
 }
```

So basically, in the constructer of the sample code, is it possible to assign a class method to a variable?

Ultimately what i want is to have an associative array with all the class methods aliased in it...that possible in php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP5.3+ (which you should be using anyway!) you can simply create an anonymous function which calls your method:

```
$this->foof = function() {
    $this->foo(1);
};
```

However, you cannot call it using `$this->foof()` - you have to assign it to a variable first: `$foof = $this->foof; $foof();`

---

In older PHP versions you cannot easily do this - `create_function()` does not create a closure so `$this` is not available there.

Comment: can we pass the parameters to the class method after it's been assigned to a variable and not in the anonymous function?

Comment: Yes, simply give the anonymous function an argument and use that one instead of the fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use anonymous functions. Just use the [Callable pseudo type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

```
$this->foof = array($this, 'foo');
...
call_user_func($this->foof);
```

Comment: not the point of the question.  the point was to be able to alias class methods to variables...so everytime i call that variable it will in effect be a reference to that class method...

Comment: the answer is correct. maybe this isn't what you wanted, or not your ideal answer, but its definitely what you asked for(which was vague). It works just the same if you save it to $f and then call via `$f(55);`

Comment: ya after you edited it makes sense.  Before the edit, it didn't answer the question.

Comment: I never edited my answer. you asked to alias a method to a variable. my answer does, and i even showed you a way to call the function. you never said you had to call it via some specific syntax.

Comment: how do i add a parameter to the call_user_func?